# about relative pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns

I am wondering whether the omission of the relative pronouns is correct for the following sentence:

1. Older adults *who are* more socially isolated are more likely to experience depression.
2. Older adults more socially isolated are more likely to experience depression.

Are both of the sentences above correct?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The style in #2 is done, but it's not particularly good.

Answer (score 2):

1 is correct. 2 is almost correct.

Past participles can directly modify nouns, but they need to precede the noun. So, you just need to move "*older adults*" to after "*isolated*":

"**More socially isolated older adults are more likely to experience depression.**"

Comment: +1 "Almost correct" is exactly right. And moving it there creates a better parallel structure, for lagniappe.